# How to access id of product in asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using OnlineStoreApi.Models;

namespace OnlineStoreApi.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        /*private readonly mystoreEntities1 _myObj = new mystoreEntities1();*/


        #region Variables
        DataClasses1DataContext _context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        ProductModel products;
        #endregion
        public IEnumerable<ProductModel> GetALLProducts()
        {


            var prods = from item in _context.spGetProducts().ToList()
                        select new ProductModel
                        {
                            Id = item.id,
                            ProductTypeId = item.ProductTypeId,
                            VendorId = item.VendorId,
                            OldPrice = item.OldPrice,
                            Price = item.Price,
                            ProductCost = item.ProductCost,
                            PictureId=item.PictureId,
                            PictureBinary=item.PictureBinary.ToArray(),
                            MimeType=item.MimeType
                        };
                      return prods;
        }


        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            products = new ProductModel();
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }


    }
}
```

Hi guys, another problem with webapi.I am not able to display details of a product using id. Whenever i type /api/Product/1 all the products are displayed.But the product with id 1 should be displayed. I am not understanding what to do. And another problem is that error occurs in FirstOrDefault method. I dont know why it says ProductModel does not contain definition about FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Can you check the `products` field? Make sure this field value

Comment: what about it please specify it

Comment: Do you get the value of **id** parameter in `GetProduct` method ? and whats the error in `FirstOrDefault` method?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is the `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` extension method in BCL. If `ProductModel` not implement those interface, You can not use `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: What I assume you need is `IEnumerable<ProductModel> products = GetALLProducts(); var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calling `.FirstOrDefault()` on an instance of `ProductModel` which does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`. Instead call it on the method which returns the collection

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
  products = new GetALLProducts();
  var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create services. dont forget SOLID.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult GetPostById (int id)
    {
        var result = _postService.GetById(id);

        if (result == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
```